# How to make math symbols bigger?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, fontsize, scaling

Is there a way to make math symbols bigger?

Reason: I've used `\sfrac{q}{m}`, and those symbols appear far to small, so I would like to make them a bit bigger.

**edit:** I just thought that `\sfrac{q}{m}` should look nicer if it is bigger when it is followed by `=`.

**edit 2:** Context:

```
some text
\[
  \dfrac{q}{m} \propto \frac{4\pi{r^2}}{\frac{4}{3}\pi{r^3}}\
  \propto 3{r^\alpha}\text{, \quad gdje je\quad}\;\alpha = -1 \text{.}
\]
some text
```

Comment: Do you really mean `\sfrac`? I don't know this command. Moreover, a bit of context would help.

Comment: use `\dfrac` instead

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: I thought that it would look nicer, but it doesn't... I'll use `\dfrac`

Comment: @an_ant: Well, you still didn't give us context (and you let me figure out myself that it's in the `xfrac` package ...). It might well be that in your context, using `q/m` would be better than `\dfrac{q}{m}`. Please be more specific by giving a complete example with not just the equation but also the surrounding text.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: Sorry! Fine now?

Comment: @an_ant: Better, but it doesn't show one important thing: Is the math formula in display style (on a line of it's own), or is it just within the text (so-called inline math)?

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: Display style; but has some text in itself.

Comment: @an_ant: OK, I'll edit your question accordingly; hope that's OK.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Another possibility are the `\mathlarger` and `\mathsmaller` commands provided by the [relsize](http://ctan.org/pkg/relsize) package.

These can be iterated to make bigger and bigger

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{relsize}
 \begin{document}
 \[
    x+y=z \leftrightarrow \mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{(x+y=z)}}}
 \]
 \end{document}
```

[image]

It doesn't always work well with large operators, though.

Answer (score 15):

It is really advisable to always provide a minimal example. The easiest way to scale it (you essentially scaling the font) is to use the `\scalebox` macro from the `graphicx` package as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\begin{document}
 Scale at 1.5 times  \scalebox{1.5}{\sfrac{3}{2}}

 This is much larger  \scalebox{3}{\sfrac{3}{2}}
\end{document}
```

You can place the whole thing in a new macro if you wish:

```
\newcommand\scaledfrac[2]{\scalebox{2}{\sfrac{#1}{#2}}}

\scaledfrac{3}{2}
```

Comment: One should add that only in very special contexts it is advisable to do this. But as no context is specified so far ...

Comment: @Hendrik Absolutely, the context is important and one should relax and let TeX\LaTeX help with the typography - that is their greater point. Also one should have some faith in the advice of people that designed packages around the difference of a solidus and a virgule! However, if you need to scale anything normally `scalebox` and `scalefont` are great tools.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to the version of **edit 2** that I just produced myself ...

As your math formula is in display style, you can just use `\frac{q}{m}`; this will give you a large fraction. It's also OK to use `\dfrac{q}{m}`; this will yield the same result: `\dfrac` just puts a fraction in display style.