# How do I make math symbols bigger?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, fontsize

I'm using Scrivener to convert multimarkdown to LaTeX and then using TeXshop to typeset my document.This work flow works great for me except for the fact that I'd like to be able to make certain math symbols bigger i.g. the integral sign. I've tried doing this like this:
`\bigint`, `\Biggint`, etc but that doesn't work. I'm sure there is a syntax that does this but I can't find it.

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7462/how-to-make-math-symbols-bigger

Comment: See also [Big integral signs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39192/5001). The `relsize` package and its `\mathlarger` command in particular may be of use to you.

Answer (score 2):

For integral symbols try `\usepackage{bigints}`. With the `amsmath` package, you can change the size of equations with the standard LaTeX resizing commands. Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Normal size:
\[
  \sum_{i=0}^n\int_{a_i}^{b_i}f(x)
\]
Large size:
{\large
\[
  \sum_{i=0}^n\int_{a_i}^{b_i}f(x)
\]}
$\sum\int_a^b f(x)$ is normal size and {\huge$\sum\int_a^b f(x)$} is huge size.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works for a "pure" latex document but not for my workflow described above.

Answer (score 0):

Write those equations directly with latex in your document, MMD will not process anything inside html comments. Just make sure your editor preferences are not ``correcting'' automatically double dashes to em quotes and you'll be fine.