# Big integral in lmodern

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Big integral sign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/big-integral-sign)

How can I get a large integral sign in the Latin Modern font? If I remove the 2nd line from the following, it works fine (printing an integral, and the same integral with enlarged integral sign). But if I leave it as is, the two integrals turn out identically. (The `relsize` package doesn't help either.)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{bigints}
\begin{document}

    \begin{align}
    \int_{-Y}^{Y}\left(\frac{X}{\frac{X}{\frac{X}{X}}}\right)dX
    \end{align}

    \begin{align}
    \bigints_{-Y}^{Y}\left(\frac{X}{\frac{X}{\frac{X}{X}}}\right)dX
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot test it now, but if you exchange the order of the packages (i.e. `bigints` first, `lmodern` second), does it help?

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39181/5001. This is a specific query about how to use `bigints` and `lmodern`.

Answer (score 10):

For dubious reasons, `lmodern` loads the "math extension" font only at a fixed size. You can correct this behavior by declaring it in a different way:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{bigints}

\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{lmex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}{<-> lmex10}{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    \int_{-Y}^{Y}\left(\frac{X}{\frac{X}{\frac{X}{X}}}\right)dX
    \end{align}

    \begin{align}
    \bigints_{-Y}^{Y}\left(\frac{X}{\frac{X}{\frac{X}{X}}}\right)dX
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

I won't show the result which is awful. Please, avoid the "big integrals".

Answer (score 1):

it does not work with the math fonts of Latin Modern, use CM math instead:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bigints}
\renewcommand\familydefault{lmr}% uses lm only for text
\begin{document}
foo\textit{bar}
  \begin{align}
    \int_{-Y}^{Y}\left(\frac{X}{\frac{X}{\frac{X}{X}}}\right)dX
  \end{align}

  \begin{align}
        \bigint\limits_{-Y}^{Y}\left(\frac{X}{\frac{X}{\frac{X}{X}}}\right)dX
  \end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]