# Ugly alignment (size of square root symbol) with Latin Modern at 12pt

Tags: spacing, symbols, amsmath, latin-modern

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}   
\usepackage{amsmath}            
\usepackage{lmodern}    

\begin{document}
    \[ \sqrt{\frac{m}{n}} \]    
\end{document}
```

The output is a different square root symbol than with merely Computer Modern, where it fits well. What's the problem with Latin Modern in this case? Why does it yield a different (why not the same) and ugly output although it is ought to be an improvement of Computer Modern. Is it better to use Latin Modern than Computer Modern? Why? I see that Latin Modern causes more problems. What should I do? Is `lmodern` somehow in conflict with `amsmath`?

Comment: You can reproduce using `amsmath`. I recommend editing your code to reflect that, as it sill be easier to get the attention of the person most likely to know the answer to your question.

Comment: The body of your posting still states that "m" and "n" are too far away from the fraction line. Is that, in fact, still the issue?

Comment: No, it's the square root symbol which causes the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have (re)discovered an important weakness in the Latin Modern math fonts. If we look at `omxlmex.fd` we see

```
% This file belongs to the Latin Modern package. The work is released
% under the GUST Font License. See the MANIFEST-Latin-Modern.txt and
% README-Latin-Modern.txt files for the details. For the most recent version of
% this license see http://www.gust.org.pl/fonts/licenses/GUST-FONT-LICENSE.txt
% or http://tug.org/fonts/licenses/GUST-FONT-LICENSE.txt

\ProvidesFile{omxlmex.fd}[2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern]

\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{lmex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}{%
   <->sfixed*lmex10%
   }{}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `omxlmex.fd'.
```

This means that the math extension font is loaded at a fixed size, 10pt, independently of the document font. Let's try with

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt{\frac{m}{n}}+\sum\frac{m}{n}+\int\frac{m}{n}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let's change `10pt` into `12pt` (with `11pt` the problem is the same, but it's somewhat less easy to see):

[image]

Do you see? The fraction grew bigger, the symbols didn't. It's more evident if we typeset the example at 17pt (with `extarticle`):

[image]

### Solution

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}{%
  <-7.5> cmex7
  <7.5-8.5> cmex8
  <8.5-9.5> cmex9
  <9.5-> cmex10
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt{\frac{m}{n}}+\sum\frac{m}{n}+\int\frac{m}{n}
\]
\end{document}
```

And ask the Latin Modern team to fix this embarrassing glitch. Maybe if they get tons of mail they'll reconsider it.

[image]

### Update

One can do `\usepackage{fixcmex}`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fixcmex}

\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt{\frac{m}{n}}+\sum\frac{m}{n}+\int\frac{m}{n}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That means, with your solution Latin Modern behaves like Computer Modern within the math mode overall? Is Computer Modern always better in math mode than (default) Latin Modern? How can I compare the definition file of LM to that one of CM?

Comment: @Thrash This only changes the `largesymbols` font; the rest of math is still Latin Modern.

Comment: Are there any further differences between between the math modes of CM (with enabled `amsmath`) and LM?

Comment: By the way, the following additional lines solve the problem, too.

`\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{lmex}{}`
`\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}{<-> lmex10}{}`

as you wrote here some years ago:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74623/big-integral-in-lmodern#74629

(redefining nearly such as in the LM file, but without `sfixed*`)

Answer (score 3):

To reproduce the issue you've encountered, it's crucial that the document font size be set to `12pt`. Loading the `lmodern` and `mathtools` packages may be more of a side show.

I take it that you don't like the fact that the horizontal rule of the square root symbol is too close to the letter "m". To fix this issue, you could insert a `\mathstrut` directive in the first argument of `\frac`. If you have a lot of `\frac` terms, you may want to set up a dedicated macro called, say, `\myfrac`, that automatically inserts a `\mathstrut` in the numerator terms. This is what's done in the third expression of the following example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}           
\usepackage{lmodern,mathtools}
\newcommand\myfrac[2]{\frac{#1\mathstrut}{#2}}    
\begin{document}
\[ 
\sqrt{\frac{m}{n}} 
\quad 
\sqrt{\frac{m\mathstrut}{n}} 
\quad 
\sqrt{\myfrac{m}{n}} 
\]    
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you must use `12pt` as the main document size, you may want to consider switching from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX and the `unicode-math` package. Doing so will yield much better spacing between the numerator term and the horizontal portion of the square root symbols, whether or not the `amsmath` package (or its superset, the `mathtools` package) is loaded. (If you do choose to load `mathtools`, you should do so before loading `unicode-math`.)

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex  % tested with MacTeX2017
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
%\usepackage{mathtools} % optional         
\usepackage{unicode-math}   
\begin{document}
\[ 
\sqrt{\frac{m}{n}} \quad \sqrt{\frac{m\mathstrut}{n}} 
\]    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60812/discussion-on-answer-by-mico-ugly-alignment-size-of-square-root-symbol-with-la).

Answer (score 2):

This modifies the font configuration for Latin Modern in a way which I ***think*** is analogous to the modifications `amsmath.sty` makes for Computer Modern. It is not exactly analogous because Computer Modern provides additional sizes of the maths extension font, whereas Latin Modern provides only 10pt. However, it does seem --- in ***absolutely minimal*** testing --- to work in a similar way.

## *Caveat emptor ...*

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\makeatletter
% \usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
% from omxlmex.fd
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{lmex}{}
% modified from amsmath.sty
\ifnum\cmex@opt=7 \relax
  \DeclareFontShape{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}{%
    <-8>lmex10<8>lmex10<9>lmex10%
    <10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>lmex10%
  }{}%
  \expandafter\let\csname OMX/cmex/m/n/10\endcsname\relax
\else
  \ifnum\cmex@opt=\z@ % need to override cmex7 fontdef from amsfonts
    \begingroup
    \fontencoding{OMX}\fontfamily{lmex}%
    \expandafter\let\csname OMX+cmex\endcsname\relax
    \try@load@fontshape
    \endgroup
    \expandafter\let\csname OMX/cmex/m/n/10\endcsname\relax
    \def\cmex@opt{10}%
  \fi
\fi
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \[ \sqrt{\frac{m}{n}} \sqrt[3]{\frac{m}{n}} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern adjustments]

Comment: I'm not at all convinced this is right.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a practical solution (for pdfLaTeX). One can set the option `nomath` for `lmodern`. Then the usual CM (with the improved output caused by `amsmath`) is used in math mode while LM is used in text mode.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}   
\usepackage{amsmath}            
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}    

\begin{document}
    \[ \sqrt{\frac{m}{n}} \]    
\end{document}
```

The `amsmath` package improves the square root symbol by changing the original IBBYVH+CMEX10 font to MNPEHI+CMEX10. However, if `lmodern` is fully enabled, `amsmath` doesn't have any influence.

Alternatively, one can use the package `ae` instead of `lmodern`, see here:
[Latin Modern vs cm-super?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/latin-modern-vs-cm-super/65103)

Comment: `ae` is not recommended at all. And those fonts are not different. `amsmath` does not change `IBBYVH+CMEX10` to `MNPEHI+CMEX10`. Those fonts are both `cmex10`. You are just looking at the fonts embedded in your document. Those are different subsets of the same font. pdfTeX does not embed the entire font but only subsets of the font. It adds those codes to distinguish the subsets.

Comment: Why is `ae` not recommended at all? Thanks for explaning the font situation!

Comment: You probably should ask somebody who's been using TeX longer than me, as it was considered deprecated when I started using TeX. I don't think it covers the T1 encoding range properly, but I'm not certain.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/latin-modern-vs-cm-super/65103#comment10897_1406 re. `ae` and why you shouldn't use it or recommend it.

Comment: Copy and paste works for me with `ae`, too.

Comment: I imagine it will work for some things, but not others.