# Fontsize not affecting some math symbols.

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

When I use `\fontsize{foo}{bar}{baz}` to increase the font size, not all the maths symbols increase accordingly. For example, the `\int`, `\sqrt` (display style) and lines when drawing fractions don't increase accordingly.

e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm,fontenc,physics,lmodern,nicefrac}
\begin{document}
{\fontsize{50}{62.500000}{\rmfamily $\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R}^{} \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}} \exp(-\dfrac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})} \dd{x} = 1 $}}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

whereas without the fontsize command everything looks as it should:

[image]

Is there a package I can add or ***a small fix*** to sort this out?

**What I've tried so far**

I thought adding `\DeclareMathSizes{50}{45}{35}{25}` to the preamble would sort this out but it appears not.

**Why the massive font?**

This is actually output from using Python's matplotlib package, ultimately stemming from this issue [Matplotlib some LaTeX symbols not scaling with increased figure sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51937267/matplotlib-some-latex-symbols-not-scaling-with-increased-figure-sizes) which [based on this answer](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11901#issuecomment-415255305), is a result of what LaTeX is producing. Hence if I can figure out how to get LaTeX to produce the right out put then I can look at modifying matplotlib's behaviour. Hence **a very minimal modification would be preferred**.

Comment: This is the same problem as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375823/ and the cure is to use `cmex` as in my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the same problem as in [Ugly alignment (size of square root symbol) with Latin Modern at 12pt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375823/)

A minimal cure is to load `fixcmex`. Also, `lmodern` should be loaded earlier.

I wouldn't use neither `physics` nor `nicefrac`. Also it doesn't make much sense to load `fontenc` with no option.

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern,amsmath,amssymb,bm,physics,nicefrac,fixcmex}
\begin{document}
{\fontsize{50}{62.500000}{\rmfamily 
$\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R}^{} \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}} 
\exp(-\dfrac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})} \dd{x} = 1 $}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I believe loading `fontenc` without option is rather useless, isn't it?

Comment: @campa Yes, I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Just what I needed, Thanks. Also, I forgot about fontenc. Also, is there a justification for erring away from physics and nicefrac? Nicefrac I occasionally use, but physics I use heavily.

Comment: @oliversm `physics` is, in my opinion, a collection of badly written macros. Also, the fractions of `nicefrac` are good for recipe books, not for mathematics.

Comment: I have just seen that this solution doesn't play well with `\mathbbm{1}` from the `bbm` package. I will open up a separate question shortly, but perhaps there is a minimal fix to this answer?

Comment: cf. [Fontsize not affecting some bbm symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480743/106804).

Comment: @oliversm That's a completely different problem. Do you *really* want to use a bitmap font?

Comment: In honesty I don't know what a bitmap font is, and I always use `\mathbb{...}` rather than `\mathbbm{...}`. However, for the indicator function for sets `\mathbbm{1}` is exactly the symbol I am after. I not attached to the `bbm` package, just this symbol. Perhaps it can be mimicked, but that seems like re-inventing the wheel given `bbm` exists.

Comment: @oliversm Enlarge at the maximum view and you'll see what bitmap means.

Comment: @egreg, quite ugly when zoomed in.