# Prettying up this equation from Mathematica

Tags: math-mode, equations, formatting, wolfram-mathematica

I like to type in 2d maths into Mathematica and then generate latex code for it. It has been working fine so far until I attempted this expression:

```
TeXForm[HoldForm[
  S (k*L) = (4*l + 1)/
    2 (Integrate[
      LegendreP[2*l, x]*SphericalBesselJ[0, 1/2*kl*x], {x, -1, 1}])^2/
    Integrate[SphericalBesselJ[0, 1/2*kl*x]^2, {x, -1, 1}]]]
```

The output latex is

```
S (k L)=\frac{(4 l+1) \left(\int_{-1}^1 P_{2 l}(x) j_0\left(\frac{\text{kl} x}{2}\right) \,
   dx\right){}^2}{2 \int_{-1}^1 j_0\left(\frac{\text{kl} x}{2}\right){}^2 \, dx}
```

Which looks like this when compiled.

[image: Mathematica generated code]

As you can see there are many style errors (in my  opinon). The Integral signs are too small with limits too big, the brackets look weird. The ^2 does not seem in the right place. The problem is if I were to type this out by hand, I come to pretty much the same code as mathematica.

Any help on making this equation  beautiful is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses the directive `\displaystyle` in both the numerator and the denominator of the fraction. (The `align` structure is used purely to simplify the before/after comparison.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \DeclareMathOperator macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\kl}{kl}   % what does "kl" stand for?
\DeclareMathOperator{\dee}{d\!} % "differential operator"
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\text{before:}\quad&
S (k L)=\frac{(4 l+1) \left(\int_{-1}^1 P_{2 l}(x) j_0\left(\frac{\text{kl} x}{2}\right) \,
   dx\right){}^2}{2 \int_{-1}^1 j_0\left(\frac{\text{kl} x}{2}\right){}^2 \, dx}\\
\text{after:}\quad&
S (k L)=\frac{\displaystyle (4 l+1) \biggl(\int_{-1}^1 P_{2 l}(x) j_0\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\kl x\right) \dee x\biggr)^2 }{\displaystyle 2 \int_{-1}^1 j_0\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\kl x\right)^2 \dee x}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is very pleasing to mine eyes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide which packages are loaded. I assume minimal and have to change \text with \mathrm.

You can find more information by searching here for large integral sign, such as in [Big integral sign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/big-integral-sign)

If you take out the {} before the exponents they'll be placed higher. I also assume you're looking for display math.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{,bigints}
\begin{document}
\[S (k L)=\frac{(4 l+1) \left(\bigintsss_{-1}^1 P_{2 l}(x) j_0\left(\frac{\mathrm{kl} x}{2}\right) \,
   dx\right)^2}{2 \bigintsss_{-1}^1 j_0\left(\frac{\mathrm{kl} x}{2}\right)^2 \, dx}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see the posting [Why is \\[ ... \\] preferable to $$ ... $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) for reasons for *not* using `$$` in LaTeX documents.

Comment: Hi, this did improve it a bit, but Mico's code made it phenomenally better. Thanks for your time though.