# How to write a big integral in an " align" environment?

Tags: align

I would like to write a big integral in a align environment but bigint seems to be useless. Could anyone suggest?
Here is a MWE containing the long expression:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{bigints}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
P(r, \omega) \propto \bigint_{h \in I} 
{\left(  \left(  \frac{r}{L} \right)^2 + c \left( \frac{\eta}{L}  \right)^2 \right)^{(1-h)/2}}
{\exp \left(  -\frac{L \omega}{2}  \left(  \left(  \frac{r}{L} \right)^2 + c \left( \frac{\eta}{L}  \right)^2 \right)^{(1-h)/2} \right)}\\\nonumber
\left( \left( \frac{r}{L} \right)^{3-D(h)} + c \left( \frac{\eta}{L} \right)^{3-D(h)} \right)
dh.
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/big-integral-sign

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes He said that it was not professional but with me it doesn't work at all. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I tried your code in a basic document and it worked fine. Please edit your question so that it includes a complete example that reproduces the problem (from `\begin{document}` to `\end{document}`). Without this it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: @IanThompson Thanks. I have just edited the code. Did you get a big integral??

Comment: Yes. I get a big integral with your example code as well.

Comment: @IanThompson Okay thanks! It seems that I have a problem with Kile.

Comment: I get output from your code, but I would not have seen it. It's really awful. Why not saying `P(r,\omega)=\int_{h\in I}f_1(h)f_2(h)f_3(h)\,dh`, explaining what `f_1`, `f_2` and `f_3` are in an `align*` environment below?

Comment: @egreg Thanks! I wanted to write the whole equation to see things better. I feel annoyed when I see the int too small.

Comment: Look at http://i.stack.imgur.com/3ApWZ.png to see what I mean. Isn't it better?

Comment: @egreg yes it is nice thanks. However I wrote the following before it: By plugging the equation A and B into C and using the fact that D, one can write .. and I give this long expression. I wanted to show it without splitting. Could you please find out a way to do that? Thanks

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik I don't think that seeing it as a big formula can help; it just puts a huge formula which adds nothing.

Comment: @egreg okay! no problems. I would also prefer to know how for the future formulas. We may then interrogate about the finality of defining align in Latex if it could add nothing ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that loads the `bigints` package and employs that package's `\bigintsss` macro to create a slightly-enlarged integral symbol. If `\bigintsss` is too large for your taste, try `\bigintssss`; `\bigintss` creates a symbol that's definitely too large for the present example.

In the present case, I would also recommend that you place the limit-of-integration term *below* rather than to the right of the integral symbol. This helps fit the first line inside the text block. I've also moved the `\nonumber` instruction, and I've used square brackets instead of round parentheses for the three pairs of outer "fences".

By the way, I have encountered no problems using the `bigints` package inside an `align` environment. I have found, though, that `bigints` doesn't seem to be compatible with the `lmodern` package; I have no idea as to *why* these two packages aren't compatible.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{bigints}
\begin{document} 
\begin{align}
P(r, \omega) 
&\propto \bigintsss\limits_{\mkern-18mu h \in I}  % use '\mukern-18mu' to shift limit to the left
\biggl[  \left(  \frac{r}{L} \right)^2 + c \left( \frac{\eta}{L}  \right)^2 \,\biggr]^{(1-h)/2}
\exp \biggl[  -\frac{L \omega}{2}  \left(  \left(  \frac{r}{L} \right)^2 +  
    c \left( \frac{\eta}{L}  \right)^2 \right)^{(1-h)/2} \,\biggr] \nonumber\\
&\qquad\times\biggl[ \left( \frac{r}{L} \right)^{3-D(h)} + 
    c \left( \frac{\eta}{L} \right)^{3-D(h)}\, \biggr] \,dh.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: A potential visual improvement may result from aligning the two opening square brackets vertically, as is done in the following example. This example also uses `\bigintssss` instead of `\bigintsss`.

[image]

```
\begin{align}
P(r, \omega) 
\propto \bigintssss\limits_{\mkern-18mu h \in I} % using "\bigintssss" now
&\biggl[  \left(  \frac{r}{L} \right)^2 + c \left( \frac{\eta}{L}  \right)^2 \,\biggr]^{(1-h)/2}
\exp \biggl[  -\frac{L \omega}{2}  \left(  \left(  \frac{r}{L} \right)^2 + c \left( \frac{\eta}{L}  \right)^2 \right)^{(1-h)/2} \,\biggr] \nonumber\\
{}\times{}&\biggl[ \left( \frac{r}{L} \right)^{3-D(h)} + c \left( \frac{\eta}{L} \right)^{3-D(h)}\, \biggr] \,dh.
\end{align}
```

Comment: Consider using the alignment character `&` *after* the `\bigint` limits, which avoids using the (arbitrary) `\qquad` for spacing.

Comment: @Werner - Thanks for this suggestion. I've posted a second example that incorporates the idea, along with `\bigintssss` instead of `\bigintsss`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably bigint doesn't work with align. Here  is an alternative way to increase the size of your integral:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{bigints}


\def\stretchint#1{\vcenter{\hbox{\stretchto[220]{\displaystyle\int}{#1}}}}
\def\scaleint#1{\vcenter{\hbox{\scaleto[3ex]{\displaystyle\int}{#1}}}}
\def\bs{\!\!}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
P(r, \omega) \propto {\scaleint{9ex}}_{\bs {h \in I} }
{\left(  \left(  \frac{r}{L} \right)^2 + c \left( \frac{\eta}{L}  \right)^2 \right)^{(1-h)/2}}
{\exp \left(  -\frac{L \omega}{2}  \left(  \left(  \frac{r}{L} \right)^2 + c \left( \frac{\eta}{L}  \right)^2 \right)^{(1-h)/2} \right)}\\\nonumber
\left( \left( \frac{r}{L} \right)^{3-D(h)} + c \left( \frac{\eta}{L} \right)^{3-D(h)} \right)
dh.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

And it works!

Comment: I don't think your claim that "Probably bigint doesn't work with align" is correct; see my answer for successful uses of `\bigintsss` and `\bigintssss` in an `align` environment. You mentioned earlier that you want the integral symbol(s) to look "professional". IMNSHO, the "tall" integral symbol that's produced by your `\scaleint` macro is rather skinny and also too upright relative to the built-in slant of TeX's math italics (which is picked up the ordinary "large" integral sign and is preserved in the integrals produced by the macros of the `bigints` package).