# Integral symbol with high and low dashes

Tags: symbols

How do I make the following integral symbols in Latex?

[image]
[image]

I know how to make an integral and the limit. I don't know how to make it with the lines through it.

Comment: Have you checked detexify?

Comment: Yes I just have. Didn't know about it. It only finds an integral with a line through it in the middle.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Do both symbols mean something different (i.e. upper/lower limts or something like that)? If not, it might just be a choice of the font used.

Comment: Those symbols rather look a giant `f` letter than a true integral symbol

Comment: The are used by my professor in relation to the riemann integral. One is defined as infimum and one as supremum from the Darboux upper or lower sum.

Comment: The most similar I know is `\fint` and `\fintop` of package `esint`. Perhaps `esint.sty` could be a good starting point to make another custom integral symbol.

Comment: after a fair amount of research trying to find examples of these integral symbols, it seems to me that a more common notation uses the shapes of the unicode characters U+2A1B and U+2A1C, with horizontal bars below and above the integral.  if someone can provide a reference to published examples of these "variants", i will be happy to propose them to the unicode committee as recognized variants.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the code from the entry [The Principal Value Integral symbol](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-prinvalint) (which defines the macro `\dashint`) in the *TeX FAQ* as a starting point, it is reasonably straightforward to define two new macros, `\lowdashint` and `\highdashint`, that place a "dash" symbol -- actually, a "minus" symbol -- a bit lower and a bit higher, respectively, than `\dashint` does.

In the code below, the macros `\lowdashint` and `\highdashint` are set up only for display-style and text-style math modes. (I can't imagine they'll occur in expressions in first-level, let alone second-level, subscripts and superscripts. However, please tell me if this assumption is invalid.)

You should, of course, feel free to change the vertical positions of the dashes -- cf the arguments of the `\lower` and `\raise` commands -- to suit your stylistic preferences.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath}
\def\Xint#1{\mathchoice
    {\XXint\displaystyle\textstyle{#1}}%
    {\XXint\textstyle\scriptstyle{#1}}%
    {\XXint\scriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}%
    {\XXint\scriptscriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}%
      \!\int}
\def\XXint#1#2#3{{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1{#2#3}{\int}$}
    \vcenter{\hbox{$#2#3$}}\kern-.5\wd0}}
\def\dashint{\Xint-}

\def\Yint#1{\mathchoice
    {\YYint\displaystyle\textstyle{#1}}%
    {\YYYint\textstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}%
    {}{}%
    \!\int}
\def\YYint#1#2#3{{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1{#2#3}{\int}$}
    \lower1ex\hbox{$#2#3$}\kern-.46\wd0}}
\def\YYYint#1#2#3{{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1{#2#3}{\int}$}
    \lower0.35ex\hbox{$#2#3$}\kern-.48\wd0}}
\def\lowdashint{\Yint-}

\def\Zint#1{\mathchoice
    {\ZZint\displaystyle\textstyle{#1}}%
    {\ZZZint\textstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}%
    {}{}%
    \!\int}
\def\ZZint#1#2#3{{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1{#2#3}{\int}$}
    \raise1.15ex\hbox{$#2#3$}\kern-.57\wd0}}
\def\ZZZint#1#2#3{{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1{#2#3}{\int}$}
    \raise0.85ex\hbox{$#2#3$}\kern-.53\wd0}}
\def\highdashint{\Zint-}

\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{@{}lccc@{}}
\toprule
\text{Math mode} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{\text{Integral symbol}}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
& \texttt{\string\lowdashint} 
& \texttt{\string\highdashint}
& \texttt{\string\dashint} \\
\midrule
\texttt{\string\displaystyle} 
& \displaystyle \lowdashint_M f
& \displaystyle \highdashint_M f
& \displaystyle \dashint_M f \\[4ex]
\texttt{\string\textstyle} 
& \lowdashint_M f
& \highdashint_M f
& \dashint_M f \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. I never would have known how to do this. Your assumption was correct by the way.

Answer (score 1):

One way of placing bars through math characters is to use `\ooalign.` In the two
commands I've defined below, the first number controls how high the bar is on
the integral sign, the second controls the length of the bar, and the third
controls the thickness of the bar.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\stI}{%
\ooalign{\hidewidth $\int$\hidewidth\cr\rule[1.1ex]
{1ex}{.4pt}}}

\newcommand{\stII}{%
\ooalign{\hidewidth $\int$\hidewidth\cr\rule[-0.1ex]
{1ex}{.4pt}}}

\begin{document}
\[\stI_m f\]
\[\stII_m f(x)\]
\end{document}
```

To get these looking nice, you might also want to read this answer: [Big integral sign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/big-integral-sign)

Comment: With this setup, the `m` symbol is placed in the "ordinary" subscript position, rather than much lower near the lower edge of the integral symbol.

Comment: One fix is to wrap the ooalign with \mathop{}. That being said, I think your solution is better.