# How can I find or implement a symbol in LaTeX type of \fint, but having tilda (\sim) crossing the \int?

Tags: symbols

I tried

```
\newcommand{\pathint}{\mathrel{\int\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\sim}}
```

It looks Ok, but it does not hold integration limits right.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Does [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character) help?

Comment: Also, there's a closed path integral `\oint`, and other integration symbols from other packages given in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) linked from cfr's comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're looking for a version of the [Principal Value Integral](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-prinvalint) symbol, but with the centered "dash" symbol replaced with a "tilde" or `\sim`. Building on some code given in [an earlier answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204565/5001), you could define a macro called `\simint` using the code given below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\Yint#1{\mathchoice
    {\YYint\displaystyle\textstyle{#1}}%
    {\YYint\textstyle\scriptstyle{#1}}%
    {\YYint\scriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}%
    {\YYint\scriptscriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}%
      \!\int}
\def\YYint#1#2#3{{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1{#2#3}{\int}$}
    \vcenter{\hbox{$#2#3$}}\kern-.52\wd0}}

\def\simint{\Yint\sim}

\begin{document}
$
 \displaystyle 
 \simint_a^b f \quad
 \simint\limits_a^b f \quad
 \textstyle 
 \simint_a^b f
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mico: Thank you so much! This piece of code is simply beautiful. I really enjoyed reading it. And it works great in my LyX! I only finetuned it a bit by changing -.52 to -.50. Thanks again and Happy New Year!

Comment: @VladimirVolodin - Glad to know the code is useful. :-) By the way, if you want to reduce slightly the size of the `\sim` symbol that crosses the `\int` symbol, you could change `\textstyle{#1}` to `\scriptstyle{#1}`, and `\scriptstyle{#1}` to `\scriptscriptstyle{#1}`, in the definition of the `\Yint` macro.