# How to use alignat with two alignment tabs containing one 'cases' environment equation and a really long equation?

Tags: align, alignat

I want the middle 5 equations to be aligned at the = and at the 'on'. I tried to use `alignat` environment for this, but unfortunately it won't work at all. The  'on...' parts keep going beyond the right margin, and I'm not sure why. I want to keep the bottom equation 'separate', so that it doesn't need to be aligned in two places with the rest of the equations, only at the = (due to its length). Below is the code I have tried which I need to fix, and a picture of it when compiled. [image]

```
   \begin{alignat}{2}
\phi &= \begin{cases}
-1 & \text{on }\textbf{$\Gamma$}^{(1)}, \\
+1 & \text{on }\textbf{$\Gamma$}^{(2)} 
\end{cases}
\\
-\Gamma u+\frac{a}{\kappa}u&=\Lambda p &&\text{on }\mathcal{A}
\\
p&=\mathbf{P}(\phi) &&\text{on }\mathcal{B}
\\
[u]^{(2)}_{(1)}&=0 &&\text{on }\gamma
\\
[\nabla_\Gamma u]^{(2)}_{(1)}\cdot\mu&=0 &&\text{on }\gamma
\\
[\nabla_\Gamma u]^{(2)}_{(1)}\cdot\mu&=0 &&\text{on }\gamma,\\
\widehat{\alpha}\mathcal{K}&=-\widehat{b}H_\alpha+\widehat{q}\dashint_\gamma H_\gamma\:{\textrm d}\gamma+\left(\frac{4\kappa\Lambda}{R^2}+2\sigma\Gamma\right)\left(u-\dashint_\gamma u\:{\textrm d}\gamma\right) \\
&\qquad-\kappa\Lambda^2\left(\mathbf{P}(\phi)^{(1)}+\mathbf{P}(\phi)^{(2)}-\dashint_\gamma \mathbf{P}(\phi)^{(1)}+\mathbf{P}(\phi)^{(2)}\:{\textrm d}\gamma\right)
&&\quad\text{on }\gamma.
\end{alignat}
```

I want the 'on..'s to be at least closer to the rest of the equations, not so far over to the right of the page. Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm guessing its leaving that gap because of the last equation, but I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you really want to align all those equations?

Comment: I wouldn't align neither the equals signs nor the conditions.

Comment: @mickep, yes, I do want to align them. :)

Answer (score 1):

The following uses only 1 alignment point, and therefore resorts to `align` only. All elements to the right of `=` in the first six equations are set in zero-width (math) boxes, then jumped over by `3em` to set their respective `on X` clauses. The final equation is set using `aligned` as in [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638315/5764), with a minor hack (zero-width `r`ight-aligned math box) to align with the rest of the equation set.

The above finagling works because the largest LHS and RHS (used for placement with `align`; in this case equations 5/6 for LHS and 7 for RHS) can stand on their own. If adjustments were to involve them, some more legwork may be needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example

\usepackage{amsmath}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638315/5764, with thanks
\makeatletter
\newcommand\X@int[1]{%
  \mathop{}\!%
  \mathchoice
    {\XX@int\displaystyle\textstyle{#1}}%
    {\XX@int\textstyle\scriptstyle{#1}}%
    {\XX@int\scriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}%
    {\XX@int\scriptscriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}%
  \int
}
\newcommand\XX@int[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox0{$#1{#2#3}{\int}$}%
  \vcenter{\hbox{$#2#3\!$}}\kern-.5\wd0
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand\dashint{\X@int-}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\mathbox@##1##2{\makebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\mathbox@##1##2{\makebox{$##1##2$}}}
  \mathpalette\mathbox@{#3}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \phi &
     % Mimic \begin{cases}...\end{cases}
    = \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
      \mathbox[0pt][l]{
        \left\{\begin{array}{ @{} r}
          -1 \\
          +1
        \end{array}\right.}
      \hspace{3em}
      \begin{array}{ @{} l}
        \text{on $\mathbf{\Gamma}^{(1)}$,} \\
        \text{on $\mathbf{\Gamma}^{(2)}$}
       \end{array} \\
  -\Gamma u + \frac{a}{\kappa} u &
    = \mathbox[0pt][l]{\Lambda p}
      \hspace{3em}
      \text{on $\mathcal{A}$} \\
  p &
    = \mathbox[0pt][l]{\mathbf{P}(\phi)}
      \hspace{3em}
      \text{on $\mathcal{B}$} \\
  [u]^{(2)}_{(1)} &
    = \mathbox[0pt][l]{0}
      \hspace{3em}
      \text{on $\gamma$} \\
  [\nabla_\Gamma u]^{(2)}_{(1)} \cdot \mu &
    = \mathbox[0pt][l]{0}
      \hspace{3em}
      \text{on $\gamma$} \\
  [\nabla_\Gamma u]^{(2)}_{(1)} \cdot \mu &
    = \mathbox[0pt][l]{0}
      \hspace{3em}
      \text{on $\gamma$,} \\
  &\begin{aligned}
    \mathbox[0pt][r]{\widehat{\alpha} \mathcal{K}} &
    = -\widehat{b} H_\alpha + \widehat{q} \dashint_\gamma H_\gamma\:\mathrm{d}\gamma 
      + \biggl(\frac{4 \kappa \Lambda}{R^2} + 2 \sigma \Gamma \biggr) \biggl(u - \dashint_\gamma u\:\mathrm{d} \gamma \biggr) \\
    & \phantom{{}={}} - \kappa \Lambda^2 \biggl( \mathbf{P}(\phi)^{(1)} + \mathbf{P}(\phi)^{(2)} - \dashint_\gamma \mathbf{P}(\phi)^{(1)} 
      + \mathbf{P}(\phi)^{(2)}\:\mathrm{d}\gamma \biggr) \text{ on $\gamma$.}
  \end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `gather` for this type of display.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204565/ with fixes
\makeatletter
\newcommand\X@int[1]{%
  \mathop{}\!%
  \mathchoice
    {\XX@int\displaystyle\textstyle{#1}}%
    {\XX@int\textstyle\scriptstyle{#1}}%
    {\XX@int\scriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}%
    {\XX@int\scriptscriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}%
  \int
}
\newcommand\XX@int[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox0{$#1{#2#3}{\int}$}%
  \vcenter{\hbox{$#2#3\!$}}\kern-.5\wd0
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand\dashint{\X@int-}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\phi =
  \begin{cases}
  -1 & \text{on }\textbf{$\Gamma$}^{(1)}, \\
  +1 & \text{on }\textbf{$\Gamma$}^{(2)} 
  \end{cases}
\\
{-}\Gamma u+\frac{a}{\kappa}u=\Lambda p \quad\text{on }\mathcal{A}
\\
p=\mathbf{P}(\phi) \quad\text{on }\mathcal{B}
\\
[u]^{(2)}_{(1)}=0 \quad\text{on }\gamma
\\
[\nabla_\Gamma u]^{(2)}_{(1)}\cdot\mu=0 \quad\text{on }\gamma
\\
[\nabla_\Gamma u]^{(2)}_{(1)}\cdot\mu=0 \quad\text{on }\gamma
\\
  \begin{aligned}
\widehat{\alpha}\mathcal{K}=
  &-\widehat{b}H_\alpha
     +\widehat{q}\dashint_\gamma H_\gamma\,\mathrm{d}\gamma
     +\left(\frac{4\kappa\Lambda}{R^2}+2\sigma\Gamma\right)
      \left(u-\dashint_\gamma u\,\mathrm{d}\gamma\right)
  \\
  &-\kappa\Lambda^2\left(\mathbf{P}(\phi)^{(1)}
   +\mathbf{P}(\phi)^{(2)}
   -\dashint_\gamma \mathbf{P}(\phi)^{(1)}
   +\mathbf{P}(\phi)^{(2)}\,\mathrm{d}\gamma\right)\quad\text{on }\gamma.
  \end{aligned}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, thanks for your reply :)