# Automatic split and left align a long equation

Tags: equations, align

I have a long equation. I want to split and align left for that equation such that same "=" location. I used below code in latex. But it fails to display. Thanks

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
 \begin{equation*}\label{proof_lemma:3} 
            \begin{aligned}
            \frac{\partial E(\mu,\sigma,\theta,\beta)}{\partial \beta}=\int_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\partial r_i(x)}{\partial \beta}dx \\
            =-\int_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{( \mu-\sigma- \theta)}{\sigma_i}\right)dx\\
    -\int_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{( \mu-\sigma- \theta)}{\sigma_i}\right)dx-\int_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{( \mu-\sigma- \theta)}{\sigma_i}\right)dx-\int_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{( \mu-\sigma- \theta)}{\sigma_i}\right)dx
            \end{aligned}
             \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please update the code to something that complies on its own

Comment: I updated it. Please check it

Answer (score 8):

Use the `={}&` trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{apptools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial E(\mu,\sigma,\theta,\beta)}{\partial \beta}
={}& \int\limits_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\partial r_i(x)}{\partial \beta}\diff x \\
={}& -\int\limits_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{( \mu-\sigma- \theta)}{\sigma_i}\right)\diff x
     -\int\limits_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{( \mu-\sigma- \theta)}{\sigma_i}\right)\diff x\\
   & -\int\limits_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{( \mu-\sigma- \theta)}{\sigma_i}\right)\diff x
     -\int\limits_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{( \mu-\sigma- \theta)}{\sigma_i}\right)\diff x
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Note how I defined a macro for the differential symbol and used `\int\limits` in order to push the Omega below the integral symbol, which is customary in this case.

Note that `hyperref` should be loaded last among the packages you have.

[image]

Comment: I am very thankful to you. It is very nice answer.

Comment: I just asked you a small question that is when I use \frac to show the division such as one of term above. The integration symbol appears very small. Let see that $\frac{\int\limits_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{( \mu-\sigma- \theta)}{\sigma_i}\right)\diff x}{\int\limits_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{( \mu-\sigma- \theta)}{\sigma_i}\right)\diff x}$

Comment: And I found that your solution may be error if \left( in first line, and \right) in second line, is it correct. I just got ! Extra }, or forgotten \right.<template> }$\hfil \endtemplate ...mega} \left( \log (\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_i)\\

Comment: @user8430 For scaling integral sign see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/big-integral-sign

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `aligned` environment like it follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \label{proof_lemma:3} 
    \begin{aligned}
        \frac{\partial E(\mu,\sigma,\theta,\beta)}{\partial \beta}&=\int_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\partial r_i(x)}{\partial \beta}dx \\[\jot]
        &=-\int_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{( \mu-\sigma- \theta)}{\sigma_i}\right)dx -\int_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{( \mu-\sigma- \theta)}{\sigma_i}\right)dx\\[\jot]
        &\quad -\int_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{( \mu-\sigma- \theta)}{\sigma_i}\right)dx
        -\int_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{( \mu-\sigma- \theta)}{\sigma_i}\right)dx 
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Note `&=` and `&\quad`.

I have added `\\[\jot]` to leave more space between the lines, but this is matter of choice.

[image]

Comment: How about if \left ( ....\\ (first line) &\quad \right) (second line) It has error

Comment: @user8430 You have to use `\right.` at the end of the first line and `\left.` at the beginning of the second line.