# Small integral symbol

Tags: equations, symbols

I can't understand why an integral of a fraction doesn't resize the integral symbol by itself.

```
$\text{SAR}=\int_{campione}\dfrac{\bf{\sigma}(r)|\bf{E}(r)|^2}{\bf{\rho}(r)}dr$
```

[image]

I saw this [Big integral sign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/big-integral-sign) but with `bigints` nothing changes (and yes, I loaded the package and I erased all those files that work like a cache). I wouldn't write an instruction to make this resize

Comment: INHO, using `\dfrac` in an inline math expression is almost surely an error. If you need to use `\dfrac`, switch to displaymath style; a side benefit will be that the integral symbol becomes large automatically.

Comment: Comment aside`\bf{\sigma}` won't produce a bold **σ**. For this you should use `\boldsymbol{\sigma}` or `\bm{\sigma}` if you load the `bm` package.

Comment: I wrote `\bf` instead `\bm`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need

```
$\text{SAR}=\displaystyle\int_{\mathit{campione}}\dfrac{\bf{\sigma}(r)|\bf{E}(r)|^2}{\bf{\rho}(r)}\,dr$,
```

if it really is an inline, not displayed, math. If not, a solution may be as follows:

```
\[
\text{SAR}=\int_{\mathit{campione}}\dfrac{\bf{\sigma}(r)|\bf{E}(r)|^2}{\bf{\rho}(r)}\,dr
\]
```

Using `\bf` in LaTeX is not recommended. You have, e.g., `\mathbf{}`.