# What kind of integral is this?

Tags: integral

can anyone tell me what kind of package or what to type for getting an integral like this on the image, where the `\frac{happines}{time}` is below death? All the integrals I can find will push the frac to after death.

[image]

Comment: So.. the older one gets the less happiness contributes to one's life?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With the help of the `bigints` package (cf. [Big integral sign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/big-integral-sign)), and some negative space, using Steven's code as a starting point.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{bigints}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathit{Life} = \hspace{-0.8em} \bigint_{\mathit{birth}}^{\mathit{death}}\hspace{-2.5em}\frac{\mathit{happiness}}{\mathit{time}} \Delta \mathit{time}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 21):

Using `bigints` is a good start.  Negative kerning is then needed around the equality and before the fraction.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[osf]{Baskervaldx} % tosf in text, tlf in math
\usepackage[baskervaldx,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bigints}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \textit{Life} \mkern-2mu = \mkern-18mu
  \bigints_{\textit{birth}}^{\textit{death}} \mkern-42mu
  \frac{\textit{happiness}}{\textit{time}} \,\Delta \textit{time}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's a start.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
\[
\mathit{Life} = \int_\mathit{birth}^\mathit{death}\frac{\mathit{happiness}}{\mathit{time}} \Delta \mathit{time}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

More refined:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{scalerel,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathit{Life} {\,=} \!\!\!\!\vcenter{\hbox{%
  $\displaystyle{\scaleto[2em]{\int}{60pt}}_{%
    \mkern-27mu\mathit{birth}}^{\mathit{death}}$}}\mkern-44mu%
      \frac{\mathit{happiness}}{\mathit{time}}\,\Delta\,\mathit{time}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP wanted to push the fraction to the left, and increase the height of the integral, so that the fraction is actually below the upper limit (death).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes that is exactly what i'm looking for.

Comment: @Hogfeldt Please see refinement

Comment: @TorbjørnT. But of course....  The final brushstrokes were still being applied.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution that uses the `mtpro2` package and its `\XXL\int` construct.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\[
\textit{\Large Life}=\XXL\int_{\mathrlap{\textit{birth}}}^{\mathrlap{\textit{death}}}
  \mkern-15mu\frac{\textit{happiness}}{\textit{time}}\Delta\textit{time}
\]
\end{document}
```