# mtpro2 and mathdesign: to adapt integral sign at two (or more) different fractions

Tags: symbols, mtpro, mathdesign

Looking the picture below it is possible to observe the same lenght of the the size of two signs of the integral.

[image]

For the first integral **(red box)**, the size is correct. But for the second integral **(violet box)** the size is very small for the integrand. I have adjusted myself the lenght of the first integral.

But, how is possible to add a command (or more commands with different sizes) into my source to have a correct size for the second integral?

I have seen this link [Big integral sign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/big-integral-sign) but I hope alone to find the right length about.

Thanks a lot to everybody and any further suggestions are always welcome.

Here there is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry} 
\usepackage{times} % Use the Times font for headings
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} 
\usepackage{classico}
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{mathtools}


%%%%%%% New integral with mathdesign %%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\def\upintkern@{\mkern-7mu\mathchoice{\mkern-3.5mu}{}{}{}}
\def\upintdots@{\mathchoice{\mkern-4mu\@cdots\mkern-4mu}%
 {{\cdotp}\mkern1.5mu{\cdotp}\mkern1.5mu{\cdotp}}%
 {{\cdotp}\mkern1mu{\cdotp}\mkern1mu{\cdotp}}%
 {{\cdotp}\mkern1mu{\cdotp}\mkern1mu{\cdotp}}}
\newcommand{\upiint}{\DOTSI\protect\UpMultiIntegral{2}}
\newcommand{\upiiint}{\DOTSI\protect\UpMultiIntegral{3}}
\newcommand{\upiiiint}{\DOTSI\protect\UpMultiIntegral{4}}
\newcommand{\upidotsint}{\DOTSI\protect\UpMultiIntegral{0}}
\newcommand{\UpMultiIntegral}[1]{%
  \edef\ints@c{\noexpand\upintop
    \ifnum#1=\z@\noexpand\upintdots@\else\noexpand\upintkern@\fi
    \ifnum#1>\tw@\noexpand\upintop\noexpand\upintkern@\fi
    \ifnum#1>\thr@@\noexpand\upintop\noexpand\upintkern@\fi
    \noexpand\upintop
    \noexpand\ilimits@
  }
  \futurelet\@let@token\ints@a
}
\makeatother

\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{mdbch}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mdbch}{m}{n}{ <->s * [1]  mdbchr7v }{}%old 0.8
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mdbch}{b}{n}{ <->s * [1]  mdbchb7v }{}%old 0.8
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mdbch}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * mdbch/b/n}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{uplargesymbols}{OMX}{mdbch}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{uplargesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{mdbch}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upintop}{\mathop}{uplargesymbols}{82}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upointop}{\mathop}{uplargesymbols}{"48}

\DeclareFontEncoding{MDB}{}{}
\DeclareFontFamily{MDB}{mdbch}{}
\DeclareFontShape{MDB}{mdbch}{m}{n}{ <->s * [0.8]  mdbchrmb }{}
\DeclareFontShape{MDB}{mdbch}{b}{n}{ <->s * [0.8]  mdbchbmb }{}
\DeclareFontShape{MDB}{mdbch}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * mdbch/b/n}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{MDB}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathdesignB}{MDB}{mdbch}{m}{n}%
\SetSymbolFont{mathdesignB}{bold}{MDB}{mdbch}{b}{n}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upintclockwise}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{128}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upointclockwise}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{130}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upointctrclockwise}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{132}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upoiint}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{134}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upoiiint}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{136}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\upint}{\DOTSI\upintop\ilimits@}
\newcommand{\upoint}{\DOTSI\upointop\ilimits@}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
dx=\upint \frac{dy}{\log x}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\upint\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\dfrac{(n(y))^2}{c^2}-1}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Integrals don't change size; adapt the function instead, for instance using `^{-1/2}`.

Comment: I had tried it at my house but I do not like the style `^{-1/2}`. I have tried also, `$\tfrac, \sfrac, $` etc. If it is not possible, I will place the square root in the numerator . Thanks a lot.

Comment: The question here, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/big-integral-sign, may be of some interest.