# \mathlarger with htlatex not supported : looking for other alternatives

Tags: formatting, tex4ht, htlatex, mathjax

I tried to use `\mathlarger` with integrals with `htlatex` but the MathJax page generated doesn't seem to support `\mathlarger` : you can see the result on this link :

[Issue with \mathlarger](http://31.207.34.24/test_debug/content_finalse4.html)

Latex source :

```
\begin{equation}
P_{a}(x)\cdot P_{b}(x)=\mathlarger{\int}_{-1}^{+1}\,P_{a}(x)\,P_{b}(x)\,dx
\label{eq18}
\end{equation}
```

Are there other alternatives to circumvent this issue with htlatex ?

Comment: please add a full sample document and a configuration you used for the conversion. it will be necessary to provide some definition of `\mathlarge` for mathjax

Comment: Did you ask at the MathJax users Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mathjax-users?

Comment: Did you see the posting [Big integral sign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39181/5001)? In particular, did you try using the macros of the [bigints](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bigints?lang=en) package: `\bigintssss`, `\bigintsss`, `\bigintss`, `\bigints`, and `\bigint`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide mathjax declaration for the `\mathlarge` command. It can be done using the following configuration file:

```
\RequirePackage{mathjax-latex-4ht}
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\unexpanded{<script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({ TeX: {Macros : {  mathlarger: ["{\\large \#1}",1] }}});</script>}}}
\EndPreamble
```

It uses `mathjax-latex-ht` package from the [helpers4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht) bundle for MathJax loading. The declaration is added using:

```
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\unexpanded{<script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({ TeX: {Macros : {  mathlarger: ["{\\large \#1}",1] }}});</script>}}}
```

This is configuration code for MathJax, you can use commands supported by MathJax to change the font size.

This is the result:

[image]

I've used a following mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  P_{a}(x)\cdot P_{b}(x)=\mathlarger{\int}_{-1}^{+1}\,P_{a}(x)\,P_{b}(x)\,dx
  \label{eq18}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: -@michal.h21.Thanks ! I am going to test it