# Resize integral symbol in the same way of a delimiter

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39192/177) addresses the possible way to typeset a bigger integral sign, but one has to choose the right size of the symbol that better fits the situation.

My question is: why can't we resize the `\int` symbol as we usually do for common delimiters `()`, `[]` and `\{\}`?

By writing

```
\left\{ \left[ \left( stuff \right) \right] \right\}
```

delimiters are automatically sized with respect to  `stuff` and the preceding/subsequent delimiter.

Why can't we write

```
\left \int \left\{ \left[ \left( stuff \right) \right] \right\} \right.
```

so that the `\int` symbol is automatically sized, too?

Comment: most fonts only have  the integral and summation in two sizes, they are not really delimiters that should stretch, but stylized S and Sigma characters

Comment: Indeed, they are not delimiters. But from a practical point of view, they are treated almost likewise, at least from an aesthetical point of view (maybe).

Comment: well not really \sum can't scale at all and \int you could only scale if it has a vertical style , actually I think there is at least one tex font package that does scale int but I'm out of time now, may look later if no one has answered

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin Please, don't. Four story or bigger fractions are evil and should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin This said, look at [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXXrS.png) taken from the manual of an available package. I have no doubt whatsoever which realization to prefer, namely the one on the left.

Comment: Have you seen the posting [Big integral sign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39181/5001)?

Comment: @Mico the old answer doesn't cover the newer OpenType Math fonts though.

Comment: @egreg don't worry: I don't mean to. And I am glad that the meaning of  things is put on top of aesthetics, though! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Opentype Math fonts can make use of the Integral extension character U+23AE

[image]

I'm not sure I like the result but this is Cambria Math with LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria math}

\begin{document}


\[
\Uleft\Udelimiter 0 0 "222B
\begin{pmatrix}
  1
\end{pmatrix}
\Uright.
\rightarrow
\Uleft\Udelimiter 0 0 "222B
\begin{pmatrix}
  1\\2
\end{pmatrix}
\Uright.
\rightarrow
\Uleft\Udelimiter 0 0 "222B
\begin{pmatrix}
  1\\2\\3\\4
\end{pmatrix}
\Uright.
\rightarrow
\Uleft\Udelimiter 0 0 "222B
\begin{pmatrix}
  1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6
\end{pmatrix}
\Uright.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you can put limits on these extended integrals though.