# How to automatically make integral size fit the integrand?

Tags: typography, size, integral

The integral sign is too small in this MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{wasysym}  provides \varint but did not work
\begin{document}  
\begin{align*}
z_1(x) &= e^{ \int \omega \,dx} \\ 
       &= \int \frac{7 x -3+\sqrt{x^{2}+\left(\left(x -1\right)^{2} x^{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-x}+\sqrt{-\frac{2 \left(\left(-x^{2}+x +\frac{\left(\left(x -1\right)^{2} x^{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{2}\right) \sqrt{x^{2}+\left(\left(x -1\right)^{2} x^{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-x}+x^{2} \left(x -1\right)\right)}{\sqrt{x^{2}+\left(\left(x -1\right)^{2} x^{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-x}}}}{12 x \left(x -1\right)}dx\\
       &= {\mathrm e}^{\int \frac{7 x -3+\sqrt{x^{2}+\left(\left(x -1\right)^{2} x^{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-x}+\sqrt{-\frac{2 \left(\left(-x^{2}+x +\frac{\left(\left(x -1\right)^{2} x^{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{2}\right) \sqrt{x^{2}+\left(\left(x -1\right)^{2} x^{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-x}+x^{2} \left(x -1\right)\right)}{\sqrt{x^{2}+\left(\left(x -1\right)^{2} x^{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-x}}}}{12 x \left(x -1\right)}dx}                  
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Compiled with `lualatex` (which is what I only use) gives

[image]

I know there is [bigint](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/big-integral-sign) package which provides different sizes. But this is not what asking for as I do not want to try different sizes each time. I need the integral size to automatically adjust to fit the size of the integrand. Similar to how `\left(` and `\right)` automatically adjust to the size of what is inside.

Is there a package for this?  I tried `\varint` but it did work. the integral sign remained the same.

Comment: Potentially related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532219

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner thanks. I tried that, but could not get it to work well. also I do not think it supports limits on integrals. Also, I had to change my font. ALso, hard to use since I had to keep typing  \rightarrow 0 0 "222B stuff.

Comment: Never mind, I now see that Davis added the same concern in his comment below his answer. Wish u luck with the question.

Comment: 1) I guess that the code is generated (from Mathematica)? Maybe if that is stated in the question, people will understand better. 2) The computer modern integral is very italic and will most likely not scale well. Since you use lualatex, you can use `newcomputermodern`, which has a scalable integral sign. 3) I tried your example with scalable integrals, and since your expression has a very high numerator compared to the denominatori, it did not come out too well.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than increase the size of the integral symbol, I'd fix the way the integrand `\omega(x)` gets typeset. Once you fix the integrand, it turns out that you no longer have to worry about getting the size of integral symbol right.

I suggest you do something like the following.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document} 
\noindent
For $x\notin\{0,1\}$, put 
\begin{align*}
S(x)&=x(x-1)\\
T(x)&={[xS(x)^2]}^{1/3} \\
U(x)&=\sqrt{S(x)+T(x)} \\
V(x)&=-S(x) +\tfrac{1}{2}T(x)\\
\shortintertext{and}
\omega(x)&=\frac{7x-3 +U(x)+\sqrt{-2 [U(x)V(x)+xS(x)]/U(x)}}{12 S(x)}\,.
\end{align*}
Then,
\[
z_1(x) = \mathrm{e}^{ \int \! \omega(x) \,dx} 
       = \exp\biggl(\int \omega(x) \,dx \!\biggr) \,.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to be the **real** solution that deals with the core of the problem.