# Extensible integrals with `unicode-math`?

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

Unicode has three slots for integrals parts (U+23A0, U+23A1, U+23AE)
which should enable to build extensible integrals.
Some maths fonts (TeXGyrePagella, STIXTwoMath,…) provide these
glyphs and a recipe in \int (U+222B) to stack them (like growing delimiters).

An easy way to use them would be

`\[ \left\int ... \right. \]`

but this can't work as the `\int` character is not a `delimiter`
but an `operator`.  So I tried to define

`\def\extint{\Udelimiter"4 "0 "222B \relax}`

to make an opening delimiter out of U+222B. This works but doesn't allow
for limits to be added, a closing delimiter would be better… easy to do
but clumsy to use, here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\def\extint{\Udelimiter"5 "0 "222B \relax} % Closing delimiter
\begin{document}
\def\myformula{\frac{1-\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}}}}}}%
                    {1+\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}}}}}}}

\[\left.\vphantom{\myformula}\right\extint_{a}^{b}\myformula\,\symup{d}x\]
\end{document}
```

and the output:

[image]

Note: the formula is stupid, any mathematician would just code `\sqrt[64]{x}`
for the radical and use a normal integral, but this example shows that
growing radicals work out of the box with `unicode-math` while growing
integrals do not.

My question: I know that the ConTeXt people are working on this issue
(luametatex), any hope for improvements for lualatex/unicode-math?

Comment: Actually I don't think luametatex has anything to do with growing integral like this, but I could be wrong about this.

Comment: I guess if you really want to typeset it you can do what you did (with a few macros to make it comfortable to use), but I don't think TeX the engine is designed that way, like "just use a normal integral sign" so I don't think Unicode-math will get this feature either. See also [math mode - Big integral sign - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/big-integral-sign)

Comment: I do not really want to typeset this formula, I just wonder why it is so complicated to use existing Unicode characters.  Or is it that nobody ever used them with lualatex or xelatex?

Comment: @user202729 Support for these extensible integrals, including to place limits on them, is supported in ConTeXt luametatex. I don't know any other application that supports them. [Simple example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1FIr.png).

Comment: @user202729 it got added to lmtx recently

Comment: The Unicode integral pieces were "grandfathered" relics of pre-laser-printer composition.  In the opinion of TeX's creator, such large integrals were neither good style nor needed.  (This is merely a historical note, not a recommendation.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton OpenType math fonts allow extensible integrals just like delimiters which do not require unicode slots for the bits

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- The OpenType mechanism is almost certainly more reliable than the Unicode pieces, but I *did* say that my comment was meant as a historical note.  Those pieces were designed for line printers.  Who uses a line printer these days?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm sure egreg isn't ready to upgrade to a dot matrix printer yet

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Some of us still use quills and carbon ink.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but aren't U+23A0 and U+23A1 `\rparenlend` and `\lbrackuend` respectively, and not integral extension symbols?