# Latex: Nice abs

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

I have this expression: `|x-|x-|x-4|||`
Now, every `|` sign has the same size, but I'd like to make the outward pairs bigger.

Is it possible to do it **automatically**, or do I have to define the size of each `|` sign manually? It doesn't work with `$\left| \right|$`. In this case I have 3 abs signs. But what if there would be for example 12? Is it possible to do it **automatically**?

This works fine:

```
\[
\abs*{\VPhantomL x-\abs*{\VPhantomM x-\abs{x-4}}}
\]
```

[image: This works fine]

But the inline version doesn't:

```
$\abs*{\VPhantomL x-\abs*{\VPhantomM x-\abs{x-4}}}$
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this-similar question
[How to make math symbols bigger?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7462)

Comment: It is very hard to not post `\DoMoreSitups` as an answer.

Comment: I'd try hard *not* to write such formulas in the first place. :) My (professional) opinion is that things like this live only in high school textbooks, and they shouldn't.

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: I converted your post to a comment because links to other answers or questions do not qualify as new answers. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @MartinScharrer:Thanks, shall keep it in mind for next time :-)

Comment: related (possible duplicate?) [absolute-value-symbols](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/absolute-value-symbols)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

TeX also offers a primitive parameter to always make delimiters grow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\delimitershortfall-1sp
\newcommand\abs[1]{\left|#1\right|}
\begin{document}
\[
\abs{ x-\abs{ x-\abs{x-4}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

gives the desired output.

[image]

`\delimitershortfall` is meant to measure how much larger the content is allowed to get before the delimiters start growing, but by setting it to a negative value delimiters always grow.

Comment: Wow!! Never heard of this before!!  There was a question here about parenthesis automatically increasing the more nesting there was -- perhaps this would be applicable there.  I think I would add the `\delimitershortfall-1sp` as part of the `\abs` macro so that the effect of this localized.

Comment: @PeterGrill Of course, modify as appropriate. Though if part of the `\abs` macro, still other delimiters inside the `\abs` would be affected, so it must be explicitly reset before the `#1`. In my documents, I like **all** delimiters to grow ;-)

Comment: @StephanLehmke OH THANKS! It's the best solution! I'll use this with  
braces too!

Answer (score 19):

As egreg commented, for this specific case you could also use the optional parameter to the commands declared with `DeclarePairedDelimiter` and specify the size:

```
 \abs[\Big]{x-\abs[\big]{x-\abs{x-4}}}
```

[image]

### Note:

- The `\left|`, `\right|` pair only resize when there is content in between that has different vertical height.   In your case, the content all had the same vertical size and hence no resizing took place.

---

As an alternate, which might be useful in other cases (but does require more work), you could insert a `\vphantom{<content with larger vertical size>}`.

Here is a solution that inserts a different `\vphatom{}` between the pairs of `\abs` to yield:

### Notes:

- As declared below with `DeclarePairedDelimiter`, you need to use `\abs*{}` if you want the delimiter resized based on the vertical size of the content.
- You can tweak the content of the `\VPhamtomL` (large), and `\VPhantomM` (medium), to control the size of the delimiter.

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%
\begin{document}
You can use the optional paramater to \verb|\abs|:
\[
\abs[\Big]{x-\abs[\big]{x-\abs{x-4}}}
\]

With inline math $\abs[\Big]{x-\abs[\big]{x-\abs{x-4}}}$.

%------------------
\newcommand{\VPhantomL}{\vphantom{x^{2^2}}}%
\newcommand{\VPhantomM}{\vphantom{x^{2}}}%
%
or you can insert a \verb|\vphantom{}|
\[
\abs*{\VPhantomL x-\abs*{\VPhantomM x-\abs{x-4}}}
\]

With inline math $\abs*{\VPhantomL x-\abs*{\VPhantomM x-\abs{x-4}}}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\abs[\Big]{x-\abs[\big]{x-\abs{x-4}}}`

Comment: Thanks! This works!
My only problem is that it works only with \[ \] and doesn't work with $  $. Can I fix it?

Comment: @balping: Both version seem to work fine in inline math -- see updated MWE. If it does not work for you, please edit the question and provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem.

Comment: @PeterGrill I edited the question

Comment: @balping: What you posted is a code snippet, and while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.  Does it work for you if you compile the MWE I provided?  Plus have a look at the updated solution that provides a simpler version for this specific equation.

Answer (score 13):

The low-TeX (pun obviously irresistible) solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\Bigl| x - \bigl| x - | x-4 | \bigr| \Bigr|$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To whoever down-voted this answer: would you be so kind as to explain your reason for doing so? Did the pun offend you? After all, I'm pretty sure that the code itself is correct -- especially as its output is pretty much identical to that of some of the other answers.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess it's related to the boldface "automatically" in the question.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Thanks for this interesting observation. Well, the bold-facing of one instance of the word "automatically" and the addition of the second instance were applied in an edit that occurred only *after* I posted my answer. I wonder if the other answer who apparently missed this qualifier also got downvoted...

Comment: Ah, yes! One should always check the revisions of the question before downvoting.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `nath` for automatic scaling of delimiters, but keep in mind that it is incompatible with amsmath (although it does provide its own version of multiline display math environments)

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{nath}
\delimgrowth=1
\def\abs#1{\lvert#1\rvert} 

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\abs{x \abs{x - \abs{x-4}}}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]