# Can I increase the fontsize of parts of an equation?

Tags: overleaf, math-fonts

Currently I'm working on a document in LateX. I would like to increase the fontsize of a part of the equation so that the whole becomes more readable. As an example one of the formulas is presented below.

[image: Formula_1]

```
\begin{equation}
     B(x)=B_0 \cdot e^{-\frac{x}{b}} 
\end{equation}
```

As can be seen the exponent of e is very small. I would like this to be larger so it becomes better readable. Increasing the fontsize is not an option due to the non-exponents becoming too large.

I'm making use of a styling package called classicthesis and arsclassica. Since I'm inexperienced with LateX I might have overlooked the influence of these packages on the layout of formulas. If this is the case is it possible to create a local environment for my equations that makes use of a different style?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. You can see if this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7462/how-to-make-math-symbols-bigger is useful for you or to use `\dfrac` or `$^{-x/b}$`. Bye.

Comment: Perhaps `e^{\textstyle-\frac{x}{b}}`.

Comment: It seems that \mathlarger{..} works great in this case. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Just use `e^{-x/b}`. It is easier to type and to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are seven [7!] different ways to display the exponential of the fraction:

[image]

- The first item is the OP's term.
- The next two are generated by `\mathlarger` and `\textstyle` (or, equivalently, `\tfrac`), respectively; their appearance is the same. (The `\textstyle` variant was already suggested in a comment by @PeterGrill.)
- I think we can all agree that item 4 (which uses `\displaystyle` or, equivalently, `\dfrac`) is awful.
- Item 6 might be okay in a displayed equation, but not so much in inline math.
- I think items 5 and 7 look *best*, in no small part because they use inline-fraction notation instead of `\frac`. (@campa already suggested the `e^{-x/b}` solution in a comment.)

---

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{relsize}  % for '\mathlarger' macro
\begin{document}
\[
     e^{-\frac{x}{b}}                \qquad
     e^{\mathlarger{ -\frac{x}{b}}}  \qquad
     e^{\textstyle   -\frac{x}{b}}   \qquad
     e^{\displaystyle-\frac{x}{b}}   \qquad
     e^{-x/b}                        \qquad
     \exp\Bigl(-\frac{x}{b}\Bigr)    \qquad
     \exp(-x/b)
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

\mathlarger helps.

```
\begin{equation}
     B(x)=B_0 \cdot e^\mathlarger{-\frac{x}{b}} 
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: better to use `^{\mathlarger{...}}` omitting the braces here (apart from looking weird) only works due to specific accidents in the implementation of `\mathlarger` in most cases `e^\foo{x}` would be the same as `e^{\foo}  {x}` (and error if `\foo` takes arguments)