# Quantifier is too small next to dfrac

Tags: fontsize, fractions

I want to work with fractions, quantifying a fraction as single element, but `\forall` and `\exists` are being displayed too small near `\dfrac`. And mathlarger doesn't seem to work.

I know only the basics of latex and haven't found anything that resolves this problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Neutral: $\mathlarger{\exists!} \dfrac{x}{y} : \dfrac{x}{y} + \dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{c}{d}$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about `2\cdot\dfrac{1}{3}`? Would you think that the 2 is too small?

Comment: No, the number 2 is not small, 1 and 3 are natural numbers and so 2, it makes sense all have the same size. But the quantifier seems to me that he should have the same size of what follows.

Comment: I see no reason to. By the way, what would `\exists \frac{x}{y}` mean?

Comment: Have you seen any published math texts that expand quantifiers in that way? As egreg hints they are usually set as normal characters in the current font size

Comment: @egreg The op possibly means "there is only one `\dfrac{x}{y}` such that `\dfrac{x}{y} + \dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{c}{d}`" in which `\exists!` means "there is only one".

Comment: Let me suggest another solution: Replace the quantifier by “There exists...”. Quantifiers and implication arrows don’t really add any benefit to the text. Too much notation just makes the text unnecessarily heavy for the reader.

Comment: You can try `\scalebox{1.2}{$\exists!$}` by `\usepackage{graphicx}` if you want `mathlarger`. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7463/269365).

Comment: @M.Logic The existential quantifier applies to *variables*. Denoting a variable by `\dfrac{x}{y}` isn't a good choice, in my opinion. I endorse Gaussler's idea of using words, rather than difficult to interpret (and out of place) logical symbols.

Comment: @egreg Actually, if I had to pick an element in a field of fractions, I could very well find myself writing “Let x/y be an element”. But I would never write “∃ x/y”, except perhaps on the blackboard when teaching.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no, I don't.

Comment: @egreg It was intended to show the nature of the number I am working on, an ordered pair of integers, with that notation. But I understand what you said, it didn't look so weird when I thought it first time.

Comment: @Gaussler yes, it is a good point but I fear being too repetitive. (on the context i'm working)

Comment: Thank you @ChoCho66. I'll see what can be done.

Comment: @egreg `\exists!\drac{x}{y}\phi(\dfrac{x}{y})` could be seen as a shorthand for `\exists!z(z=\dfrac{x}{y}\wedge\phi(z))`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In my opinion, any kind use of symbols should be permitted as long as (1) the meaning of such use is clear, (2) such use won't bring any problems, and (3) such use is accordance with people's usual tastes on symbols.

Comment: @M.Logic did I say otherwise?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, you didn't say that clearly, and so it may be my mistake.

Comment: @M.Logic the question wording was more about typographic judgement  than what is allowed, "are being displayed too small " could be rephrased as "following standard conventions"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle More precisely, "how to get larger `\exists!` appropriately". By the way, `\exists!` in the usual size is my personal taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps what you need is a symbol which acts like a large operator. See the following codes and output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathOperator*{\bigexistsone}{\scalerel*{\exists!}{\sum}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item The original one in text style in lines: $\exists!\dfrac{x}{y}\left(\dfrac{x}{y} + \dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{c}{d}\right)$, and the new one in display style between lines: $$\exists!\dfrac{x}{y}\left(\dfrac{x}{y} + \dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{c}{d}\right).$$
\item The new one in text style in lines: $\bigexistsone\dfrac{x}{y}\left(\dfrac{x}{y} + \dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{c}{d}\right)$, and the new one in display style between lines: $$\bigexistsone\dfrac{x}{y} \left(\dfrac{x}{y} + \dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{c}{d}\right).$$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]